# Allow RTMP stream to AWS?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, nginx, network-programming

I have a EC2 micro instance running nginx and I'm trying to stream video to it using RTMP, however the security groups section doesn't have an RTMP option for allowed inbound connections.  Is there a way around this so I can stream to my server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default port for RTMP is 1935, so add a new inbound rule of type "Custom TCP Rule" and type "1935" under Port Range.

Comment: This saved me from spending day 2 on configuring this server. I went through every tutorial could not find a solution. Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

RTMP typically uses TCP over port 1935.

If you select "TCP" from the connection type list, you can then manually choose which port to allow ingress on.